# Error when casting inside arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have three classes which

```
public abstract class Animal {
    ...
}

public abstract class Cat extends Animal {
    ...
}

public abstract class Dog extends Animal {
    ...
}
```

And if i want to create an animal arraylist with dogs and cats it gives runtime casting error.

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();

animals.add((Animal) cats);
animals.add((Animal) dogs);
```

How can i create this arraylist?

Comment: You are trying to add a `List` as an element of a `List<Animal>`. Did you mean you use `addAll`?

Comment: You are casting a ``List<Cat>`` to ``Animal``. A ``List`` is not an ``Animal``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"add" will just add one element (But not a List). You want to add all elements in a List so you need to use `addAll()`:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
List<Cat> cats = new ArrayList<>();
List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();

animals.addAll(cats);
animals.addAll(dogs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your casting is wrong. With the casting in place, you are trying to assign somethings which are incompatible.

```
animals.add((Animal) cats);
```

When you say `(Animal) cats`, you are trying to cast an `List<Cat>` to `Animal`, which is wrong.

If it is adding all the elements in `cats` to `animals` is what you are looking for, you could do that with `animals.addAll(cats)`.